# Cómo hago para que un fragment se siga ejecutando mientras abro otro fragment?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragment, fragment

Mi consulta es debido a que soy nuevo en esto y estoy haciendo un cronómetro, en el cual tengo en el primer fragment un Runnable con el `TextView` ejecutandose, pero quiero que al pasar al otro fragment desde mi `BottomNavigation` no se reinicie el contador.

¿Cómo puedo solucionar este problema?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        BottomNavigationView navigation = findViewById(R.id.navigation);    //BottomNav y fragments
        navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);               //BottomNav y fragments
        loadFragment(new ChronoFragment());                                 //BottomNav y fragments

        final Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) this.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    }

    private boolean loadFragment(Fragment fragment){
        if (fragment != null){
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment).commit();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.navigation_chrono:
                fragment = new ChronoFragment();
                return true;

            case R.id.navigation_list:
                fragment = new ListFragment();
                break;

            case R.id.navigation_setup:
                fragment = new SetUpFragment();
                break;
        }
        return loadFragment(fragment);
    }
}
```

Comment: Utiliza AsyncTask hay un metodo doInbackGround

Comment: Bienvenido...Emi.., te saludamos y te damos la bienvenida al sitio!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera 
[medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]**,  te sugiero modificar tu pregunta, agregar lo que has realizado o investigado, más información, etc, saludos!

Comment: Agrega el código esencial de lo que comentas.

Answer (score -1):

//El contenido anterior fue editado totalmente, esta es otra solucion que espero pueda aportar, cualquier sugerencia es bien recibida :)

Hola compañero, quiero compartirte una solucion para mantener la referencia del conteo aunque el fragment sobre el cual tienes el cronometro no este en vista.

1) puedes crear una clase que extienda de Application en la cual puedes crear un Calendar el cual accedes por SET y GET

2) cuando inicies el cronometro estableces el Calendar creado (este quedara con el momento exacto en el cual se ha clickeado el btn del cronometro en inicio

3) lo mostrado en el cronometro basicamente seria la diferencia entre los millis del calendar guardado en la clase que extiende de Application y un Calendar.getInstance() que traeria el momento actual.

4) cada vez que el fragment que contiene el cronometro es traido muestras esta diferencia en el runnable que tienes.

generalmente para el uso de tabs uso viewpager y tablayout (por lo que mi anterior respuesta se basa en este) pero pensando en una solucion que sirve para un caso mas general te comparto este metodo que suelo usar, mas que todo cuando me piden que muestre el tiempo transcurrido despues de una publicacion, accion o edicion :)

Saludos y buena energia.

Comment: Esto no es lo que pregunta el OP, se refiere que esta realizando una transacción de fragments al dar clic a un botón.

Comment: Hola buenas tardes, disculpa. modificare mi respuesta para corresponder con lo buscado, lo siento :)

Comment: No te preocupes, al contrario @JulianCuevas  se agradece tu contribución, creo que lo mejor sería que el OP agregara un poco más de detalles y su código relevante para saber como podríamos ayudarlo.

Comment: muchas gracias, voy a probar eso a ver si funciona